# INSERT...RETURNING with output_expression

Tags: postgresql, jooq

[PostgresQL INSERTs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-insert.html) allow returning an `output_expression` using any subset of the inserted columns, but I cannot get the syntax right for using this feature with jOOQ.

This is the PL/pgSQL equivalent of what I want to achieve:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (i INTEGER, t TEXT);

DO 
    $$DECLARE my_var TEXT; 
BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO my_table(i, t) 
        VALUES(1, 'hello') 
        RETURNING (t) INTO my_var;

    RAISE NOTICE 'Inserted text was --> % <--', my_var; 
END$$;
```

But the problem I find is this syntax is invalid in jOOQ:

```
String retVal = using(configuration)
    .insertInto(MY_TABLE,
        MY_TABLE.I,
        MY_TABLE.T)
    .values(i, t)
    .returning(MY_TABLE.T)
    .fetchInto(String.class);
```

The closest I've been is using `fetchOne` to get a full `MyTableRecord` and picking the fields I want. Is there another way telling jOOQ to fetch exactly the type of variables I want?

P.D.: I'm using jOOQ 3.9.2

Comment: This is on the roadmap: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/3185

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The workaround I have found is the following, it takes advantage of Java's [Optional](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html):

```
String retVal = using(configuration)
    .insertInto(MY_TABLE,
        MY_TABLE.I,
        MY_TABLE.T)
    .values(i, t)
    .returning()
    .fetchOptional()
    .map(MyTableRecord::getT)
    .orElse(null);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.fetch().into(String.class)`

Comment: `fetch().into()` returns a `List<String>` instead of a `String`, so it doesn't compile. But even if I change the type of `retVal` to make it compile, I get this error: `org.jooq.exception.MappingException: Cannot map multi-column record of degree 2 to value type class java.lang.String`. Notice that `fetch()` returns a `MyTableRecord` instead of a `Record1` so it cannot be mapped to a `String` without extra help.